# Web Accessibility - Tab Order?

Tags: html, web, frontend

I have been tasked with going through the a11y project checklist. 
(http://a11yproject.com/checklist.html) for those who aren't sure what that is.

I noticed that on our website, (www.adn.com) when you tab through the website, it goes through our entire left-rail menu, before making it to the article content.

Is there some way to manipulate the order in which our site is "Tabbed through" for keyboard only users?

New to the industry, currently am a Junior Dev. Apologies if this is a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is `tabindex`

**w3schools example**

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" tabindex="2">W3Schools</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" tabindex="1">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/" tabindex="3">Microsoft</a>
```

Reference: [w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

Comment: Note that, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex recommend to "Avoid using tabindex values greater than 0. Doing so will make it difficult for people who rely on assistive technology to navigate and operate page content.". Instead "focus on writing them in a suitable DOM sequence".

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having isn't a tabindex issue, as the tabindex is correct for the menu's position in the DOM. (also changing tabindexes to values beyond 0 or -1 can really screw up the expected tab order for an interface).

What is going on here is that the menu has been visually hidden, by positioning it off screen, but it has not been adequately hidden from keyboard users/screen readers.

You'll need to update the CSS of your menu, so that when it is positioned off screen, the `id="slider-menu-nav-list"` is set to `display: none`.  Then when the menu button is activated, the `#slider-menu-nav-list` should be set to `display: block;`

Looking through the source code some more, you'll also have to change your Menu button into an actual `<button>` element, as it's currently keyboard inaccessible as a `<div><span>` combo, so there is currently no way for a keyboard users to actually open the menu. (not all keyboard users are blind, and it can be frustrating to not be able to see where your current keyboard focus is located).

Hope this helps!

Comment: All great info, Thank you! Looks like we have some work ahead of us. Thank you. This A11Y project is really interesting. Also working with screen-readers has been an overwhelming concept at times, respect for those who use them frequently / depend on them.